# How to read HTML element with vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to read the e-mail address from [this site](http://www.yopmail.com/en/email-generator.php).

I used this:

```vb
WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("email").GetAttribute(TextBox1.Text)
```

But its not really working. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: The element's id is `login`, not `email`, and you want to get the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this:

```
WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("login").InnerText
```

to get "something@yopmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

```
Right-click > Inspect Element > input id="login"
```

So, perhaps your code will look something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InnerText
```